# Realice una consulta en php pero me sale sin resultados

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Bueno el problema es el siguiente estoy realizando una simple consulta con un `where` dentro de `php`, ya echo algunas mas con este tipo de sintaxis y me han salido bien, sobre todo en el logueo y al insertar datos, el problema es este.
Trabajo con tres `iframes` de `javascript` y al momento de loguearme mando una variable de la clase `php` a el `iframe` numero 0 ya que ese nunca se mueve y siempre almacenara dicha variable aquí el código.

```
<script>
window.parent.frames[2].location = "../inicio.php";
window.parent.frames[0].location = "../menu2.php?nick=<?php echo $nombre;  ?>";
</script>
```

Ahí mando mi variable `php` a mi `iframe` numero 0, bueno entonces ahora ya la imprimo y se que si esta en ese lugar, después en mi clase perfil, necesito esa variable ya que dependiendo del nick del usuario se mostrara la información de su perfil y este es el código

```
$nick = "<script> document.write(window.parent.frames[0].prueba) </script>";
echo $nick;

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM usuario WHERE nick = '$nick'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "nick: " . $row["nick"] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Después como verán hago un echo dentro de la variable nick en el código de arriba y me imprime la variable dependiendo del usuario que ingreso, eso significa que me trae lo que requiero, pero al momento de poner la variable `$nick` dentro de mi consulta de `php` no me trae ningún registro, pero si lo hago por medio del id, si me tare la fila que necesito o inclusive si pongo el nick de manera directa me trae la fila, mi problema es que al poner la variable que almacena el usuario que ingreso a través del `iframe` numero cero, no me trae ni un error ni nada solo se queda en cero. alguna forma de solucionar ese ligero error, de antemano gracias por lee el Post.

Comment: Cada vez que leo estas consultas de PHP+MYSQL me dan ganas de llorar. No vayas a usar este código en una página publica, es vulnerable a ataques por SQL injection, te pueden borrar toda la base de datos.

Comment: no es para un pagina de aprendizaje, apenas estoy tratando de mejorar mi conocimientos en php, pero pues trate de que todo fuera creado desde cero y pues así salio, algo básico pero vulnerable, gracias por tu aportacion

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con David, Siempre es mejor empezar desde cero, asi se aprende con mas profundidad, yo también empece así y me ayudo mucho a comprender como funciona el lenguaje SQL.

Comment: Tranquilo David no te preocupes por la vulnerabilidad, veo que estas usando mysqli, el cual ya se encarga de proteger contra SQL injection. :)

Comment: @IvanKoop MySQLi no protege contra inyección SQL sin más, hay que usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de sentencias dinámicas. Empezar desde cero está bien siempre que se empiece de manera correcta; si se empieza con malas prácticas y mal código, corregir esos malos hábitos es difícil y "doloroso" más adelante. La seguridad debería ser esencial hasta en páginas de prueba.

Comment: Tenes razon @AlvaroMontoro, ahora me puse a leer sobre los prepared statements, tenia entendido que mysqli ya se encargaba de esa seguridad, por lo visto estaba mal informado, que suerte que me avisaste, gracias alvaro!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable nick lo que almacena es un código javascript, no una cadena de texto que debería representar el nick. Pon esto después de la definición de $nick y te darás cuenta:

```
var_dump($nick);
```

En tu  variable nick sólo debería estar el valor del nick valga la redundancia. Si tu código PHP de la consulta está en el archivo menu2.php la definición correcta de nick sería:

```
$nick = $_GET["nick"];
```

En vez de:

```
$nick = "<script> document.write(window.parent.frames[0].prueba);</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Almacena tus datos en un array y luego hace var_dump de eso para poder visualizar la estructura de tus datos:

```
$datos = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $datos[] = $row;
 }
}
//Imprimi los datos de esta manera:

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($datos);
echo "</pre>";
```

De esa manera podras tener idea de como te esta devolviendo la consulta sql y podras trabajar con facilidad.

Proba cambiando:

```
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM usuario WHERE nick = '$nick'";
```

por esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nick = '".$nick."'";
```

tambien agregale el metodo mysqli_error() para que Sql te imprima el error:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Una ultima recomendacion, para validar consultas sql no hace falta que uses mysqli_num_rows(), la consulta responde boolean te dejo un ejemplo:

```
if($result){
 //la consulta respondio TRUE
} else {
 //error en la consulta
}
```

Comment: Hola Ivan Gracias por contestar, el restultado fue este

array(0) {
}

Lo cual al parecer significa que no me esta regresando nada en mi arreglo de la consulta, entonces, creo que mi problema es que no toma la variable que le estoy asignando, de echo si le asigno alguna variable con el nick directamente de la variable, lo asimila correctamente, no se si los frames puedan ocasiónar que dicho elemento del texto no se pueda aplicar a la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

David, el paso de la variable ¿tiene que ser de esa manera? Ya que estas en plan experimental, por qué, en base a jQuery,  no aplicar un ‘listener’  para la comunicación entre los ‘frames’. Así podrás enviar un valor del frame hijo al frame padre, o viceversa.

Una vez que tengas el valor necesario, me refiero al de la variable,  podrás invocar, desde JQuery mismo, a tu código de consulta php, al mismo tiempo que le pasas dicho valor.

En caso de que no hayas trabajado con esa forma de comunicación, y te interesa conocer al respecto, visita [este sitio](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage) para empezar.

Bien por empezar desde abajo; no todos tienen tal iniciativa.